# What's the strategy for implementing an attribute of type schema.TypeMap in Terraform Provider SDKv2?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Context: we're developing a TF Provider using TF Provider SDKv2.

Consider a resource that has an attribute of type `schema.TypeMap` that should support updates. Semantically it means a list of settings for a resource.

```
"settings": {
    Type:        schema.TypeMap,
    Optional:    true,
    ForceNew:    false,
    Elem:        schema.TypeString,
},
```

```
resource "tv" "example" {
 ...
 settings = {
   "brightest" = "23"
   "contrast"  = "56"
 }
}
```

Now let's say `tv` has 50 settings where each setting has a default value and we don't want to make a user specify each 50 so we only want a user to specify settings that they want to override (for example, default value for `contrast` is `50` but user wants it to be `56` which is why they added `"contrast"  = "56"` under `settings` attribute.

We can see 2 possible implementation options that would support `Update` for `setting attribute:

1. Don't use `DiffSuppressFunc` and store only overridden settings in TF state. This hardcoding default setting values is undesirable in the client (TF Provider), this option requires API to have `overridden = true` or something to indicate whether the value is set to a default value or was overridden.
2. Save all 50 settings in TF state and use `DiffSuppressFunc` to disable the diff between empty `tf.example.settings` in `main.tf` and 50 settings saved in TF state. However in this scenario it's a little bit unclear how `Update` would be implemented.

Which option is used typically?

The only example I've found is `airflow_config_overrides` [attribute](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/b86f7963c051f36235dac30cd1f34b97fefc3079/google/resource_composer_environment.go#L320) from GCP TF Provider which solves this issue in a different way.

Comment: It sounds like `brightness` and `contrast` are specific attributes known to the remote API, rather than something decided by the user. Would it be more appropriate to define this as a nested block with explicitly-defined attribute for each one, and then you can set a default value for each in the schema?

Comment: @MartinAtkins that was not the best example, but a user should be able to decide to use a custom values for these attributes. And while your suggestion makes sense overall, let's say in this specific case there're 50+ such attributes with names like `foo.zoo.bar` so it's way easier to represent them as a map (to avoid `foo.zoo -> foo_zoo` conversions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create predictable behavior when arguments to one resource use values derived from arguments to another, Terraform has some specific constraints on what providers are allowed to do with attributes during plan and apply which I'll summarize here:

1. If an argument is set (present and not `null`) in the configuration, the provider must set the value to exactly what the module author specified when generating a plan.
2. If an argument is *known* (not "known after apply") at the planning phase, then the final value during the apply phase must exactly match the value from the planning phase.

(There are more details in the internal documentation [Resource Instance Change Lifecycle](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/main/docs/resource-instance-change-lifecycle.md), but that is intended to be read by developers of SDKs rather than developers of providers *using* the SDK, so it uses some terminology that the SDK normally abstracts away.)

Since you are defining `settings` as a single argument of a map type, the rules above apply two that argument as a whole, rather than to individual elements. Therefore it is not possible to mix both author-provided keys and provider-defaulted keys in the same map. Terraform prohibits this so that a module author can write `tv.example.settings` somewhere else in their module and know it will evaluate to exactly the value they wrote.

However, if you declare an argument that *cannot* be set in the configuration -- `Computed: true` without `Optional: true` -- then your provider can freely set that argument to whatever it wants as long as it still upholds the second rule above, of consistency between plan and apply.

Therefore the compromise I would suggest here is to declare a pair of attributes where one is author-settable and the other one is not:

```
"settings": {
    Type:        schema.TypeMap,
    Optional:    true,
    Elem:        schema.TypeString,
},
"all_settings": {
    Type:        schema.TypeMap,
    Computed:    true,
    Elem:        schema.TypeString,
},
```

(`all_settings` might not be the best name. Other names I considered were `final_settings`, `combined_settings`, etc.)

With this approach, you can set a value for `all_settings` either during plan (`CustomizeDiff`) or apply (`Create` and `Update`), depending on whether you have all of the information you need during planning or not.

The one operation that will require some extra special care with this design is the one the SDK calls `Read`, because in that case you'll need to decide whether and how to incorporate potential changes made outside of Terraform into the `settings` value. If you don't update it *at all* then Terraform will not detect and "repair" changes made outside of Terraform, because it will not see the settings to have changed.

Given the intended meaning you described in your question, I can imagine two possible implementations depending on what the provider has access to:

- If the provider itself knows what all of the default values are, `Read` could first update `all_settings` and then copy from there to `settings` the subset of values that *aren't* the defaults.

  This is the most robust solution because it allows Terraform to recognize when a change outside of Terraform has changed one of the settings from its default to a non-default value, and so to propose to reconcile it by "removing" that setting. (That is, it will show in Terraform's UI as a removal, but your implementation will internally interpret that as "set it back to the default".)
- If only the remote system knows the defaults and the provider cannot know them then I would probably compromise by first updating `all_settings` and then copying into `settings` only the subset of keys that match what was previously set in `settings`.

  This will allow Terraform to detect when a setting the author configured was changed outside of Terraform, but it won't detect situations where a setting that *wasn't* managed in Terraform (i.e. originally set to the default) changes to a different value.

If you don't foresee a need for module authors to refer to the settings they didn't explicitly set elsewhere in the module (that is, if they are unlikely to want to write `tv.example.all_settings` somewhere) then you could potentially just ignore this part entirely, in which case this reduces to what you described as option 1, with the exception that the question would not be whether the author set the value to the default or not but instead whether the author set the value *at all*. In that case, you're essentially saying that setting a particular setting in the map represents an intent for Terraform to manage that setting, and leaving a setting *unset* represents the intent to let it be chosen by the server and arbitrarily drift in future.

Any other option you can think of which conforms to the requirements I summarized at the start of this answer would be fine too. However, I don't think that your option 2 meets those requirements because it suggests that `settings` would have a different value after apply than was set in the configuration, which would violate at least one of the requirements depending on whether you deal with it during the planning phase or the apply phase.